# Ayuda con InputBox

Tags: c#

necesito si me pueden pasar codigo para realizar un InputBox de la siguiente manera:
Al dar click en el Button1 que se cargue el InputBox con un titulo "Acceso" solicitando ingresar la contraseña, al dar click en el boton Aceptar del InputBox si se ingreso como contraseña el número 100419 que mi DataGridView1 en su propiedad Enabled sea True, caso contrario si se ingresa cualquier otro dato que no sea el 100419 me devuelva con un mensaje de error dejando al DataGridView en su propiedad Enabled en False.

Muchas gracias de antemano
Sds

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca no hacemos ejercicios, pero con gusto te podemos ayudar si intentas algo y tenes un problema en particular

Comment: Que has intentado implementar ? recuerda que la diea es guiarte no hacer la tarea. Cuando dices InputBox es porque tiene que verse en una nueva ventana, no podrias ser un textbox en el mismo form donde esta el grid ? Lo pregunto porque esta algo raro que se pida acceso con un boton.

Answer (score 0):

No existen InputBox en c#, eso es de VB.

De todas formas podrías simularlo utilizando los formularios de windows.

Este seria el método que utilizaría yo

Utilizando 2 formularios y una clase

- El primer formulario es el que ya tienes donde quieres llamar al inputBox
- El segundo formulario es el inputBox simulado
- La clase debe tener una variable estática para intercambiar los valores

Paso 1:
Crear el Formulario de windows y ponerle el titulo, con un TextBox y 2 Botones (aceptar, cancelar)

Algo así:

[image: inputBox]

Paso 2:
En el formulario Base ejecutas el formulario inputBox

```
private void btnLevantarInputBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Por defecto la respuesta es cancelar
    Vista.aceptado = false;

    // Ejecuto el formulario que simula el inputBox
    var inputBox = new FormInputBox();
    inputBox.Show();
}
```

Paso 3: En este momento esta el formulario inputBox abierto con los 2 botones que tendrian un comportamiento como este

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Tu codigo de lectura y comprobacion

    Vista.aceptado = true;
    this.Close();
}

private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Vista.aceptado = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

Y por ultimo te dejo la clase que trabaja de fondo (NOTA: es importante que la variable sea estática para que mantenga almacenado los datos, y por ese mismo motivo tienes que tener el cuidado de limpiarla siempre que quieras utilizarla, ya que va a mantener el ultimo valor)

```
public static class Vista
{
    public static bool aceptado { get; set; }
}
```